# Java listening for http messages

Tags: java, web-services, http, networking, powerpoint

I have a java program that can ask client programs questions. I would like to add functionality by embedding the questions I might ask into a hyperlink so that they can be asked by clicking on that link (i.e. main use in powerpoint slides).

The generated link might look something like this: "http://localhost:port/questiondata/"
The receiving program receives the link, decrypts the question data to post the question.

Could I make it so that my program on localhost listening on the port could detect when that link is pressed/sent?
There doesn't need to be any 2 way communication and it would always be asked on localhost, can I do that simply using java sockets listening on the port, or would i need to set up some form of webserver as a median.

I know very limited stuff about how http works, and I know tcp sockets need to be 2-way. Can anyone give me a recommendation of how I could possibly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want an embedded HTTP server in your Java program (something like Jetty).

Or maybe you just need to make a web application and run that using something like Tomcat or Jetty.

> Could I make it so that my program on localhost listening on the port could detect when that link is pressed/sent?

The web server would see the HTTP request that results in the user clicking on the link.

> There doesn't need to be any 2 way communication

If you click a link in Powerpoint, it will open the page in a browser window. So your program gets to display something.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a web server embedded inside your application you can write [your own](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/javawebserver.php) 
or embed one like [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) [inside your program](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)

Comment: And if you want to embed the web browser within the presentation rather than launching a browser instance when the user clicks the link, you can do that as well.  At least under Windows; I don't believe it's possible in PPT/Mac.